# Settings shortcut in Android 4.4

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, home-screen-shortcuts

I am using Android 4.4. I would like to have shortcut to multiple Settings features (wifi, display, lock screen,...) on the desktop.

If I long click on a desktop, I do not find a way to place a shortcut. And I remember it was possible in earlier versions of Android.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in other launchers easier, but if you go to Widgets in the app drawer there should be one called SETTINGS, once you add this it will give a menu of sub settings options like Battery, WiFi etc.

Finding the 'Widgets' option depends on your device though, Google Now launcher has it when you press the menu button, Samsung Launcher has it in the app drawer, Nova Launcher has the long press function... etc.

Alternatively I strongly recommend [Power Toggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.painless.pc&hl=en) from the play store. You can add nearly any shortcut to this, though the odd one (e.g. Locations) requires root. It's a fantastic, flexible option. (I have **no** involvement with this app by the way, but I've used it for ages on all my devices)

Edit: From your comment you are using a Samsung Galaxy S5, which as you say, does not have this option. The only options I can think of are downloading widget(s) for the shortcuts you use, or downloading a new launcher like Nova Launcher that has the functionality you need. Alternatively you could just use the quick shortcuts in the notification settings, though the range of them is quite limited.

Comment: I am using Galaxy S5 and oddly there is no Settings widget :S

Comment: That... doesn't surprise me much, I'm looking at you Samsung. I don't have the S5 in the office, but I'll have a look when I get home for you.

Comment: I tried it there on my lunch, that's very odd. I've updated the answer but it's not ideal for your situation.

Comment: *[Marc Plante](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/81151/marc-plante) reports (lacking rep to comment):* "I can unfortunately add that Nova Launcher does not help Samsung Galaxy S5 owners. I use the Wifi toggle often as part of my work, and miss having it available. I have opted to leave a settings shortcut in my Nova tool drawer."